# VS2010 SQL database datagridview database query to show results

Tags: sql, database

I do not have enough reputation to post images. So here's the scenario.

PartsID in CostPrice(databse table) relies on PartsID in PartsInfo(database table).
Lets say when the PartsInfo.PartsID = 1,
In CostPrice will only show all the related information of 1.

I'm using VS2010 and i try to build a query in datagridview,

```
SELECT costprice.costid, 
       costprice.suppliername, 
       costprice.costprice 
FROM   costprice 
       INNER JOIN partsinfo 
               ON costprice.partsid = partsinfo.partsid
```

This is my query now, it still shows all the data kept in the database tables.
I would like to know the query for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CostPrice.CostID, CostPrice.SupplierName, CostPrice.CostPrice 
FROM CostPrice 
INNER JOIN PartsInfo ON CostPrice.PartsID = PartsInfo.PartsID
WHERE CostPrice = 1
```

or

```
SELECT CostPrice.CostID, CostPrice.SupplierName, CostPrice.CostPrice 
FROM CostPrice 
INNER JOIN PartsInfo ON CostPrice.PartsID = PartsInfo.PartsID
WHERE PartsInfo.PartsID = 1
```

Not sure which you want.

Comment: the problem is, the partsID is auto increment integer, it will increase by 1 each time the user add new item.

Comment: Yea I know, but WHERE PartsInfo.PartsID = 1, that means only shows information about 1, but what I want is the datagridview will show the related information according to the auto generated PartsID.

Comment: You have to give better requirements -- I've no idea what you want.

Comment: ok, I mentioned that in my question's exmaple, PartsInfo.PartsID = 1 right? what if, my PartsID is auto generated integer, and that means, WHERE PartsInfo.PartsID = 1 only shows information and data of "1". But my requirement is I want to show the related data of the integer which is auto increment, when the PartsID = 1, shows data of 1, when increase to 2, shows the data of 2 and so on.

Comment: I need to know the query of getting this requrements. Thanks

Comment: It shows the related information via the join.  Is there some other related information?

Comment: The only way you are going to explain this is to show some example data and what you expect from the select.  I suggest using sqlfiddle.com

Comment: ok last question, 
SELECT costprice.costid, 
       costprice.suppliername, 
       costprice.costprice 
FROM   costprice 
       INNER JOIN partsinfo 
               ON costprice.partsid = partsinfo.partsid 
WHERE CostPrice.PartsID = (textbox1.text from another form)

How can I pass the textbox1.text which is from another form to the query???